# How to put an image over another image when a particular event happens

Tags: android

I'm trying to learn more and trying to create a basic number generator where on a click of a button a number is generated between 1 and 90 and that number is then crossed out on an image of a board which has numbers from 1 to 90 with an image of x.

[image]

I have thought of creating 90 image views with the x image and giving them tags and making them appear when the number has been generated but this method is redundant and not efficient. I'm unable to think of new methods to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of generating 90 images. You can place a view of `X` over it and when the desired number is generated makes the `X` visible for that image.

The code for generating `X` is.

```
public class DrawX extends View {

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        float width = getMeasuredWidth();
        float height = getMeasuredHeight();
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawLine(0,0,width,height,paint);
        canvas.drawLine(width,0,0,height,paint);
    }
}
```

You can adjust height weight according to your need.